# A beginners Geth problem with getGasPrice

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I get "gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction" in web3.js when I call `web3.eth.getGasPrice()`. The error suggest that I am trying to mine a contract. I do not, I only want to get the recent gas price on Ropsten.

When I call the same function while connected to **Ganache, all works as expected**.

1. I started Geth on Ubuntu to testnet
2. I checked eth.syncing, after a while it returned "false". It has tons of ldb-data so I assume it is really synched.
3. web3.js reports it connects properly

   npm -version web3
    6.4.1 (1.0.0-beta.36)

   Geth
   Version: 1.8.15-stable

I ran out of ideas. I assume that I missed a specific use in Geth.

Answer (score 1):

After reverting all my node.js changes, I found that my Geth intance works as expected. That is confusing.

The only explanation that I can find is that Geth needs to settle down OR it wasn't synched when I reported as such.

Answer (score 0):

Without any reason, I cannot reproduce the problem after adding some annotations (console.log()) in my node modules. In other words there seems no relation with Geth.

I get the gas prices now from Geth in the range from 1000000000 to 5000000000.